# Flex 4 - How do I keep track of last selectedItem in datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid, selecteditem

I"m using Flex 4 and an AdvancedDataGrid.  I need to keep track of the previously selected item.  I can't think of where to capture this though.  In an itemClickHandler method, the grid's selectedItem value is already the current selected item.

The focusIn and focusOut attributes apply to the whole datagrid, not to just one row in the datagrid.

Thank you.
Bonnie

Answer (score 2):

```
public function yourConstructor(){
   ChangeWatcher.watch(yourAdvancedDataGrid, "selectedItem",someHandler);
}

public var oldSelectedItem:Object;

protected function someHandler(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void{
   oldSelectedItem = event.oldValue;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Another solution would be to extend your grid to add a new property like 'previousSelectedItem' and override the selected item handler.

Comment: I tried it, but the grid fires (in order) a FlexEvent and a ListEvent while the handler expect a PropertyChangeEvent, so it ends in a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on event **itemFocusOut**